# Symbolic int results in deletion of main variable (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am trying to do something like this:

```
syms x h4 t4 c13;
t = 0.6*sin(pi*x);
h1x = 0.5*(1 - t);
h0 = h1x;
h14x = -h4 -t4*(x - 0.5);
h24x = h4 + t4*(x - 0.5);
symvar(h14x)
```

which returns

```
ans =

[ h4, t4, x]
```

Then

```
u13x = (-4*int(h14x, x, 0, x) + c13)/h0
symvar(u13x)
```

returns

```
u13x =

-(c13 + 4*x*(h4 - t4/2) + 2*t4*x^2)/((3*sin(pi*x))/10 - 1/2)

ans =

[ c13, h4, t4, x]
```

and

```
p12x = -3*int(u13x, x, 0, x)
symvar(p12x)
```

which is

```
p12x =

-3*int(-(c13 + 4*x*(h4 - t4/2) + 2*t4*x^2)/((3*sin(pi*x))/10 - 1/2), x, 0, x)

ans =

[ c13, h4, t4 ]
```

As you can see from `u13x` where the variables were `[h4, t4, c13, x]`, while integrating to `p12x` it got reduced to `[h4, t4, c13]` even though the integral limits are variable (in terms of `x`). Is it a bug? I can't seem to get by this weird behaviour. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three possible workarounds (tested in R2015a).

**1. Use a symbolic function**
One option is to make the input that will be passed to `sym/symvar` a [`symfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symfun.html) in terms of `x` and then use the optional second argument to specify a finite number of variable to look for:

```
syms x h4 t4 c13;
t = 0.6*sin(pi*x);
h1x = 0.5*(1 - t);
h0 = h1x;
h14x = -h4 -t4*(x - 0.5);
u13x = (-4*int(h14x, x, 0, x) + c13)/h0
p12x(x) = -3*int(u13x, x, 0, x) % Make symfun, function of x
n = realmax;                    % 4 or greater to get all variables in this case
symvar(p12x, n)                 % Second argument must be finite integer
```

which returns the expected `[ x, t4, h4, c13]`. Just setting the second argument to a very large integer value seems to work.

**2. Convert expression to a string**
There are actually two versions of `symvar`. There is [`symvar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/symvar.html) for string inputs and [`sym/symvar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symvar.html), in the Symbolic Math toolbox, for symbolic expressions. The two forms apparently behave differently in this case. So, another workaround is to convert the equation with `int` to a character string with [`sym/char`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/char.html) before passing it to `symvar` and then converting the output back to a vector of symbolic variables:

```
syms x h4 t4 c13;
t = 0.6*sin(pi*x);
h1x = 0.5*(1 - t);
h0 = h1x;
h14x = -h4 -t4*(x - 0.5);
u13x = (-4*int(h14x, x, 0, x) + c13)/h0
p12x = -3*int(u13x, x, 0, x)
sym(symvar(char(p12x))).'
```

which also returns the expected `[ c13, h4, t4, x]` (note that order appears to be opposite of the first workaround above).

**3. Call MuPAD function from Matlab**
Lastly, you can call the [MuPAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad-1.html) function [`indets`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/indets.html) that finds indeterminates in an expression.

```
syms x h4 t4 c13;
t = 0.6*sin(pi*x);
h1x = 0.5*(1 - t);
h0 = h1x;
h14x = -h4 -t4*(x - 0.5);
u13x = (-4*int(h14x, x, 0, x) + c13)/h0
p12x = -3*int(u13x, x, 0, x)
feval(symengine, 'x->indets(x) minus Type::ConstantIdents', p12x)
```

which returns `[ x, c13, h4, t4]`. This will work if the input `p12x` is class `sym` or `symfun`. You can also use:

```
evalin(symengine, ['indets(hold(' char(p12x) ')) minus Type::ConstantIdents'])
```

The reason that `sym/symvar` doesn't work in your case is because it is based on [`freeIndets`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/freeindets.html) under the hood, which explicitly ignores free variables in functions like `int`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So as suggested in the first solution, we can explicitly define any function like that then? (by defining the main variables beforehand like you did in `p12(x)`)

Comment: @AdityaKumarPraharaj: Are you sure that's the version you're using and that you have the Symbolic Math toolbox installed? Did you `clear all` and use exactly the code in my answer? I just tested the first workaround in my own copy of R2014b and it worked fine. The second workaround works too. For the third, only the `evalin` string version works properly. As for the `p12x(x)` (not `p12(x)` as in your comment or it won't work with the rest of the code) form, see the documentation for [`symfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symfun.html) that I linked to in the first workaround.